# How to remove plastic-like reflection from visual shader?

Tags: shaders, terrain, godot, specular

The problem is that this is a piece of terrain, it should not have blue reflections like it's made of plastic. But when the camera gets close enough, these specular highlights are rendered.

[image: Terrain screenshot]

This is the shader code, but since it is set to visual, I'm using nodes (shown below).

```
shader_type spatial;
render_mode specular_schlick_ggx, async_visible;

uniform sampler2D tex_frg_15;
uniform sampler2D tex_frg_35;
uniform sampler2D tex_frg_36;
uniform sampler2D tex_frg_12;



void vertex() {
// Output:0

}

void fragment() {
// Input:8
    mat4 n_out8p0 = INV_CAMERA_MATRIX;

// Input:4
    vec3 n_out4p0 = NORMAL;

// TransformVectorMult:9
    vec3 n_out9p0 = (vec4(n_out4p0, 1.0) * n_out8p0).xyz;

// Vector:5
    vec3 n_out5p0 = vec3(0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000);

// DotProduct:6
    float n_out6p0 = dot(n_out9p0, n_out5p0);

// Texture:15
    vec4 tex_frg_15_read = texture(tex_frg_15, UV.xy);
    vec3 n_out15p0 = tex_frg_15_read.rgb;
    float n_out15p1 = tex_frg_15_read.a;

// Texture:35
    vec4 tex_frg_35_read = texture(tex_frg_35, UV.xy);
    vec3 n_out35p0 = tex_frg_35_read.rgb;
    float n_out35p1 = tex_frg_35_read.a;

// Texture:36
    vec4 tex_frg_36_read = texture(tex_frg_36, UV.xy);
    vec3 n_out36p0 = tex_frg_36_read.rgb;
    float n_out36p1 = tex_frg_36_read.a;

// VectorScalarMix:34
    float n_in34p2 = 0.50000;
    vec3 n_out34p0 = mix(n_out35p0, n_out36p0, n_in34p2);

// Texture:12
    vec4 tex_frg_12_read = texture(tex_frg_12, n_out34p0.xy);
    vec3 n_out12p0 = tex_frg_12_read.rgb;
    float n_out12p1 = tex_frg_12_read.a;

// ScalarOp:28
    float n_in28p1 = 0.70000;
    float n_out28p0 = n_out6p0 - n_in28p1;

// ScalarOp:33
    float n_in33p1 = 4.00000;
    float n_out33p0 = n_out28p0 * n_in33p1;

// VectorScalarMix:26
    vec3 n_out26p0 = mix(n_out12p0, n_out15p0, n_out33p0);

// If:27
    float n_in27p1 = 0.70000;
    float n_in27p2 = 0.00001;
    vec3 n_out27p0;
    if(abs(n_out6p0 - n_in27p1) < n_in27p2)
    {
        n_out27p0 = n_out26p0;
    }
    else if(n_out6p0 < n_in27p1)
    {
        n_out27p0 = n_out26p0;
    }
    else
    {
        n_out27p0 = n_out26p0;
    }

// If:7
    float n_in7p1 = 0.95000;
    float n_in7p2 = 0.00001;
    vec3 n_in7p3 = vec3(0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000);
    vec3 n_out7p0;
    if(abs(n_out6p0 - n_in7p1) < n_in7p2)
    {
        n_out7p0 = n_in7p3;
    }
    else if(n_out6p0 < n_in7p1)
    {
        n_out7p0 = n_out27p0;
    }
    else
    {
        n_out7p0 = n_out15p0;
    }

// ScalarOp:38
    float n_in38p0 = 0.00000;
    float n_in38p1 = 1.00000;
    float n_out38p0 = n_in38p0 + n_in38p1;

// ScalarOp:37
    float n_in37p0 = 0.00000;
    float n_in37p1 = 0.70000;
    float n_out37p0 = n_in37p0 - n_in37p1;

// Output:0
    ALBEDO = n_out7p0;
    ROUGHNESS = n_out38p0;
    SPECULAR = n_out37p0;

}

void light() {
// Output:0

}
```

[image: Node graph]

Zoom in:

[image: Texture sampling nodes]

[image: Texture mixing and output]

[image: Conditional nodes]

Comment: What happens if you zero out the Emission and Clearcoat pins?

Comment: @DMGregory 0 emissions and it just get's slightly darker, clearcot... no idea what it does, I was just trying random stuff

Comment: "No idea what it does" should translate to "I should [search to find out](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=clearcoat+shader&ia=web)". In this case, it represents a shiny clear layer on top of your material, like if you finished it with a clear glossy spray paint. That glossy coating adds plastic-y reflections to otherwise matte surfaces.

Comment: @DMGregory I could've imagined but just like in blender, in godot too... it does nothing at all.